# Conditional probability question...

Tags: probability, statistics

I was just wondering what the most simple approach to solve this problem is and why it works, I'm having a hard time reaching the solution in a manner that really makes sense to me

Tammy selects 5 marbles without replacement from a bag of 28 marbles, where there are 4 different colored marbles in the bag with 7 of each color. 
Find the probability the first 2 marbles are one color and the next 3 are another.

Comment: One way of seeing what is happening is by drawing a tree. Check which satisfy your event and calculate.

Comment: I did draw out a tree and solve it that way, however I was curious as to a faster/more straightforward way to think about solving it. I think you use conditional probability?

Comment: Yes but without you knowing, the probabilities you multiply on successive branches are conditional probabilities. They depend on what happened before hand which is the reason why they are not all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the problem restricts the order in which themarbles are picked (that is, it does not ask for the probability of 3 of one coller and 2 of another in any order among five picks), the easiest approach to understand is to multiply the probabilities, at each pick, of non failing (where a success means you have picked 2 marbles of one color, then 3 of another).

On the first pick, you can't fail; the marble picked just sets the starting color.  On the second pick you must pick one of the 6 remaining marbles of that starting color out of the 27 remaining marbles: $\frac{6}{27}$. On the third pick you only fail if you pick one of the remaining 5 marbles of the starting color; in the $\frac{21}{26}$ fraction of non-failures you set the ending color.

Then on the 4-th and 5-th picks you must select marbles of the ending color: 6 out of 25, then 5 out of 25.

The chance of success is the product of all those probabilities:
$$
1\cdot \frac{6}{27} \cdot \frac{21}{26} \cdot \frac{6}{25} \cdot \frac{5}{24} = \frac{7}{780}
$$

Comment: The solution that I have been given has 0.09 as the answer, and that was the result I came to using a tree. I don't see anything wrong with your approach though, perhaps a typo in answers confusing me then, as evidently your result simplifies to 0.009.

Comment: @Smithson The solution that you have been given is $\sim 0.009$, isn't it?

Comment: 0.00897435897...

Comment: No, 0.09, which is what has been confusing me so much.

Comment: I take that you're affirming that must be a typo then..?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what I did. We have four colors, $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$, and $c_4$. We pick without replacement 5 balls, $B_1$, $B_2$, $B_3$, $B_4$, and $B_5$.

- The probability that the first ball, $B_1$ has color $c_1$, $\mathbb{P}(B_1 = c_1)$ is:
  $$
  \mathbb{P}(B_1 = c_1)=\dfrac{7}{28}.
  $$
- The probability that the second ball, $B_2$ has color $c_1$, $\mathbb{P}(B_2 = c_1)$ is:
  $$
  \mathbb{P}(B_2 = c_1)=\dfrac{6}{27}.
  $$
- The probability that the third ball, $B_3$ has color $c_2$, $\mathbb{P}(B_3 = c_2)$ is:
  $$
  \mathbb{P}(B_3 = c_2)=\dfrac{7}{26}.
  $$
- The probability that the fourth ball, $B_4$ has color $c_2$, $\mathbb{P}(B_4 = c_2)$ is:
  $$
  \mathbb{P}(B_4 = c_2)=\dfrac{6}{25}.
  $$
- The probability that the fifth ball, $B_5$ has color $c_2$, $\mathbb{P}(B_5 = c_2)$ is:
  $$
  \mathbb{P}(B_5 = c_2)=\dfrac{5}{24}.
  $$

Thus, you get:

$$
\mathbb{P}_1=\mathbb{P}(B_5 = c_2)\cdot\mathbb{P}(B_4 = c_2)\cdot\mathbb{P}(B_3 = c_2)\cdot\mathbb{P}(B_2 = c_1)\cdot\mathbb{P}(B_1 = c_1)\\=\dfrac{5}{24}\cdot\dfrac{6}{25}\cdot\dfrac{7}{26}\cdot\dfrac{6}{27}\cdot\dfrac{7}{28}.
$$
Now you have to do this with all possible permutation of colors, namely:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
c_1& c_2 & c_3 & c_4 & c_1&c_1&c_2&c_2&c_3&c_3&c_4&c_4\\
c_2& c_1 & c_1 & c_1 & c_3&c_4&c_3&c_4&c_2&c_4&c_2&c_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Which is given simply by: $\dfrac{4!}{2!}=12$.

Therefore, you proabability that you are looking for is:

$$
\mathbb{P}=12\cdot\mathbb{P}_1=12\cdot\dfrac{5}{24}\cdot\dfrac{6}{25}\cdot\dfrac{7}{26}\cdot\dfrac{6}{27}\cdot\dfrac{7}{28}=\dfrac{7}{780}.
$$